# Problem with string to float conversion of values in pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

My pandas dataframe column which have prices are mostly in the format `r'\d+\.\d+'` , which is what you expect. But when I try to convert it astype float, it says that I have got few numbers in the format `\d+\.\d+\.\d+` like this one '6041.60.1'.
How do I go about converting all of them in the format `\d+\.\d+` with series.str.replace()? The expected result is '6041.60'.

Comment: '6041.60.1' what's the expected answer, 6041.601 or 604160.1 ?

Comment: Expected is '6041.60'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommand using .apply

```
df1["column"] = df1["column"].apply(lambda x:  "".join(x.rsplit(".",1)), axis = 1 )#remove the last "."
df1["column"] = df1["column"].astype("float")
```

Comment: How may I include the regular expression into it, as there are many other values in it in this format?

Comment: I edited it, so basically in apply i use a lambda expression, inside of it you can do whatever you want to the row. Since it's only a column, x would be the string you want to do transformation on.